# Android error: recreate() must be called from main thread

Tags: java, android

I am getting an Android error, even though the error message is quite obvious, i can't figure out how to make it work properly.

The error message is:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from main thread
        at android.app.Activity.recreate(Activity.java:4193)
```

In my app, a notification is sent to log out a user (when his token expires).

On older Android versions i am having no problems to do so, however from SDK 11 and up, i have to use the recreate() method. I get the error that it has to be called from the Main thread.

I moved the recreate() statement to the MainActivity class, this doesn't work when i call the method from the IntentService. I still get the same error. The messaging part is working just fine, just the handling of the logout message is resulting in this error.

Here are some snippets:

inside GcmIntentService.java

```
if (logout!=null) {
    VarControl.ma.logout();
}
```

inside MainActivity.java

```
public void logout() {
    deleteToken();
    closeWebView();
    restartApp();
}

public void restartApp() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        this.recreate(); // THE ERROR OCCURS HERE
    }
    else{
        //left out this part because its not relevant
    }
}
```

How can i call recreate from the Main thread (but the code has to be handled on receiving the intent) ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to run sthg on the main thread you can still do :

```
public void restartApp() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                recreate();
            }
        });
    }
    else{
    //left out this part because its not relevant
    }
}
```

Comment: this.recreate couldn't be resolved. but referring to VarControl.ma.recreate() did!!

thanks a million, exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: yes i edited shortly after, if you write this.recreate(), 'this' refers to the Runnable. You can just omit the 'this' and it will use the only context where recreate makes sense here, your activity, or specify MainActivity.this.recreate();

Answer (score 0):

Make a List that is accessible by both threads. Secure it using synchronized or anything like that. Whenever the Intent is received add a Runnable with the fitting code to the List.
In the main thread check if the list is non-empty on a regular basis. If it's not empty, pop the first Runnable from the list and run it. Do that until the List is empty.

That is generally a good way to handle passing code from one thread to the other.

Comment: thanks for the reply, how would I check the list on a regular interval? getting the Main Thread in an endless Thread.sleep loop isnt really an option for me.....